# WooCommerce get date of last order with offset

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a client shop with lots of customizations. A primary one is uses the PDF Invoices & Packing Slips for WooCommerce plugin to generate an internal, admin order print out (they are a manufacturing company). The print out has been heavily customized and isn't used as an "Invoice" at all and has many custom functions to show certain information depending on customer, products, etc.

They've asked if we can add a line (again, for internal use) to display the date of the last purchase.

Where I'm struggling is this only would show when a new order is placed, so I'd guess that a standard "get last order date" function would pull the most recent order, but I'd need the order date that was *before* that one—so a -1 offset.

Going further with an example: customer John Smith has placed 3 orders
First order: 1/25/20
Second order: 11/27/21
Third order: 10/2/2022

Their newest order gets placed today, 3/2/2023.
When the custom order production sheet prints on 3/2/2023 (after the order is paid), there needs to be a "Last order: 10/2/2022".

Is there a way I can pull the "last order date" but prior to the most recent? I should say too that the custom production sheet printouts aren't always printed the same day an order is placed—e.g. they don't work weekends, so an order placed on a Saturday doesn't get printed until Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've studied the get_last_order() WooCommerce function and the custom function below should give you the second last order object:

```
function bbloomer_get_second_last_order( $customer ) {
    
    global $wpdb;

    $order_statuses_sql = "( '" . implode( "','", array_map( 'esc_sql', array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ) ) ) . "' )";

    $second_last_order_id = $wpdb->get_var(
        "SELECT posts.ID
        FROM $wpdb->posts AS posts
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS meta on posts.ID = meta.post_id
        WHERE meta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND meta.meta_value = '" . esc_sql( $customer->get_id() ) . "'
        AND posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND posts.post_status IN $order_statuses_sql
        ORDER BY posts.ID DESC
        LIMIT 1 , 1"
    );

    if ( ! $second_last_order_id ) {
        return false;
    }

    return wc_get_order( absint( $second_last_order_id ) );

}
```

You can then use the output to [get anything related to the WooCommerce order object](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/), such as the ID or the date, e.g.:

```
if ( bbloomer_get_second_last_order( $customer ) ) {
   $second_last_order_date = wc_format_datetime( bbloomer_get_second_last_order( $customer )->get_date_created() );
} else $second_last_order_date = '';
```

Please note that $customer is the customer object, so if you have access to the customer ID you need to create the customer object in the following way before passing it to bbloomer_get_second_last_order():

```
$customer = new WC_Customer( $customer_id );
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Very interesting... I like this approach. Before I start the testing though, what happens to this function on a customers first order? Would there be a scenario where in that instance instead of having a blank or "null", could it just default to something like "Last order: not applicable" or "First order"?

Comment: You're welcome! Function would return false if there are not at least 2 orders from the same customer

Comment: So I was already defining the $customer variable a different way so I was able to modify your code a bit to (I think) make it work. Last pieces to the puzzle though: I'm outputting like so:  <h3>Last order: <?php echo $second_last_order_date ?> </h3>.  How can I reformat the date to be just month, day, and year for example? But also, if there were no previous orders, could I have it output some other text?

Comment: Cool. I've added wc_format_datetime() to the snippet, which should format the date based on the WordPress settings. Also, I've added the else part ($second_last_order_date = '') so that you can check if $second_last_order_date is empty, and in that case print the error message

Comment: So unfortunately once I got this over to my production site it falls apart seemingly due to the DB query in your function. We have 125k+ orders in our system. Running this once was slow but worked. When I try to batch it (which is what normally happens) it completely breaks and throws an error. I'd imagine there's no other way to do this without the DB query right?

Comment: WooCommerce is working on optimizing the DB and move orders to its own table. I guess once that's released it should work better (SQL statement will require some edits of course). In regard to your 125k orders, I can't of course replicate that on my own dev site, but I guess there must be some way to limit the SELECT statement. What about you only select orders from last 30 days for example?

Comment: Yeah I've been reading about the new WC DB stuff, seems really cool (and long overdue in my opinion!) but yes, until then I have to deal with this haha. Narrowing the search is definitely an interesting idea. I am far from an SQL expert, but would you have an example of what that might look like? In addition, would there be a way to also exclude orders from a specific customer ID in the query? We have a very specific wholesale customer we built a custom API for that places 30 - 50 orders per day and has 55k+ orders in the system. If they were excluded, and limited the query, that may work...?

Comment: Wherever you call bbloomer_get_second_last_order( $customer ) you can always prepend a customer ID check: if ( $customer->get_id() == 123 ) return;

Comment: You can also limit by order status: "AND posts.post_status IN ( 'wc-completed' )"

Comment: Finally, you can limit it by date: "AND posts.post_date >= '" . gmdate( 'Y-01-01', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) . "' " - this is would be for this year's orders